# Program to show USB speed

Tags: windows, usb

I'm looking for a program that can

- show the transfer speed of each connected devices. I'm not looking for the USB maximum speed i.e. the maximum signaling rate (which can be done using the [USB View utility](https://superuser.com/q/388174/116475)), nor the maximum effective throughput, but the actual, current throughput (e.g. "USB external hard drive is currently sending data at 5 MB/s to disk C").

You could imagine having all connected USB interfaces, and see the current speed, just like WhatPulse does for wifi/Ethernet connections:

[image]

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7
- other stats like total data transferred by devices, daily/weekly/monthly/yearly transfers, etc.

Comment: Try TeraCopy. Am not sure that it will meet your needs. But just try.

Comment: @TomJ Thanks, I use TeraCopy but it doesn't show the transfer speed of each connected devices (it only shows the transfer speed of copy operation that TeraCopy handles).

Comment: Alright, I have not used any of these but they look promising, [USB Monitor Pro](http://www.fabulatech.com/usb-monitor-pro.html), [USB Monitor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/usb-monitor/), [USB Analyzer](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-port-monitor/), and [USBlyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/)